# Google Chrome Live Caption Edit or Copy Text

Tags: google-chrome, browser, speech-to-text

Google Chrome has new feature for speech to text any video. (only english)

Are there any way to edit or select text in this box. İ tried some methods but. It's not a dom element. I can't edit or access this box.
I need to access this text for copy. But text in the box cant editable or copyable.

If there is any config for manage this box I can try.

https://blog.google/products/chrome/live-caption-chrome/

[Sample Live Caption Box (cant copyable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJYG6.png)

Comment: Which is the DOM element that holds the streaming text? Can the streaming text be located (may be through the Network tab of Dev Tools)?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the example is taken from YouTube, where auto-generated
text transcripts of the videos are automatically available in many cases.

- To access this feature, click the three dots menu (`...`) below the video
  and select "Transcript" from the menu
- You may be asked to select a language or you may be able select a language
  from the drop-down element. Make your choice and you’ll see a full transcript
  along with timestamps.
- You may disable the timestamps by clicking the three-points hamburger
  icon and selecting "Toggle timestamps"
- Click and drag to highlight all the text (it will scroll automatically)
  and press
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
  to copy it.

You can paste this text anywhere to create your transcript in a text file.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Transcribe YouTube Videos Automatically](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/three-ways-transcribe-youtube-videos/).

---

For other cases where the text is inaccessible, you could use an OCR product.
I have used with much success the open-source application
[greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot).
This product is very accurate and is a alternative to accessing the text-box.

Using greenshot on your second image gave  me this:
"computer power supplies output 12 volts If you apply 12 volts to a CPU
it‘ll look something like this". Pretty good and very accurate.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for answering.
YouTube solution is fine. But what about other sites? This mechanism works with speech to text. İ would like to access live caption box.

Comment: I just copied the text from your second image, which gave me this: "computer power supplies output 12 volts If you apply 12 volts to a CPU it‘ll look something like this". I used OCR with the open-source application [greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot), as alternative to accessing the text-box.

Comment: @harrymc Which is the DOM element that holds the streaming text? Can the streaming text be located (may be through the Network tab of Dev Tools)?

Comment: @mvark: For the first link in the post (and almost all embedded YouTube videos), it's simple enough to right-click the video, do "Copy video URL", enter it in the browser, and then use Transcript as above. For non-YouTube videos there is no general rule. For the DOM element  in YouTube, the Dev Tools don't seem to find it, so it might be built into Chrome.

Comment: Although YouTube was provided as an example, I think the intent of the OP & my interest too is more about the DOM element that Live Caption feature of Chrome creates irrespective of website & how streaming text gets there. So while it is good to know about greenshot's OCR capabilities, is there a way (may be through Chrome Dev Tools) to get the entire streaming text no matter if it's YouTube or any other site? How does Live Caption operate within Chrome?

Comment: @mvark: Impossible to say. The text overlay itself is invisible to the Chrome Dev Tools, in that any attempt to select it will end up selecting the HTML element underneath it (I tried). Meaning that it is not part of the DOM, but is thrown up by the Chrome browser itself.

Comment: Ok, so I guess Chrome is not injecting any DOM element although it seems like it based on how it is positioned within the web page. Or it is using a DOM element but preventing it from being accessible through Dev Tools

Comment: Your answer is not related to the OP's question. He is asking about Chrome's "Live Caption" feature — not transcripts from YouTube. Live Caption has nothing to to with .srt / .vtt / .ass or autogenerated subtitles on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know if you can access the live caption box but an easy workaround is you can screenshot the screen (Win + PrtSc) and use something like google translate to extract text.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do th same here. screenshot app would be so much time wasting but meantime would have to be that way or upload to youttube to generate subtitles

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).