# How to make Google live caption stay on the screen for a longer time?

Tags: google-chrome, caption

Google has a live caption option and when I'm playing an audio or a video and I have the live caption on the screen, it disappears quicker than I'm able to read it sometimes, I would like to know if there is a way to make it stay on the screen for longer? or alternatively is there a way to copy it and paste it or to access the live caption history?

Answer (score 0):

The live caption option is new and hard-baked into Chrome.
We don't have much control over it at all.
It is designed to be real-time, so may change faster than you can read
or capture.

If you are using YouTube, auto-generated text transcripts of the videos
are automatically available in many cases, containing the entire text
of the video.

For more information about extracting the YouTube text transcripts,
see the post
[Google Chrome Live Caption Edit or Copy Text](https://superuser.com/a/1639943/8672).